# Is it possible to modify (or create) an scheduled task in Windows command-line to disable "Stop task if it runs longer than"?

Tags: windows, command-line, task-scheduler

I wanna change this option via command line using **`schtasks`** (or whatever), but the docs seems not to have an option for it:

> Stop task if it runs longer than

only the GUI seems to allow it:

[image: Option to change - stop if it runs longer]

I have tested this method:

```
schtasks /change /tn "/MyTask" /du 5000
```

(so it lasts for 5.000 hours) but it does not change that option.
I could workaround it too by creating a new task, if modification is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although not very convenient. It's possible to set the options you need on a scheduled task and then export it into a XML file. Then we can delete all sections from XML which we don't want to change. Only mandatory section which must remain there is `<Actions>`. Without it the command does not run. Then we delete everything else and leave only what we want to modify on a scheduled task. In this case we are modifying `stop if the task runs longer then` so we leave section `<settings>` and value `<ExecutionTimeLimit>`. (note that you can also put there values which cannot be chosen in GUI) Save XML file and then you can update any existing scheduled task by running

> schtasks /create /tn taskname /ru useraccount /rp password /f /xml schtaskmodify.xml

The downside is that this is not universal and you need to know the task action command and task credentials. It also works without /ru and /rp, but then credentials of the scheduled task get reset to yours.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell `Set-ScheduledTask` and `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` cmdlets can be used modify scheduled tasks (whether created using `schtasks.exe`, `New-ScheduledTask`, the GUI, etc). Try this:

```
$TaskSettingsObject = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit '05:00:00'
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Settings $TaskSettingsObject
```

This could also be written more succinctly as a one-liner by wrapping the `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` command in parentheses so the CimInstance object is built before passing it as a `-Settings` parameter:

```
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit '05:00:00')
```